# facing “ this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB” error while moving code from VS CODE to Github

Tags: github

remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: fbca711e560293d49079568727b024244cd246d7cab72c2dfff845c389ce812c
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File lib/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework is 123.38 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/elearning-fyp/hellojifyp.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't typically allow files larger than 100 MB in repositories.  In this case, you have such a file because you checked in `node_modules`, which is definitely not recommended.  You should not check in any binary dependencies or build products into your repository.  Absent a compelling reason, you should not check into any non-binary dependencies in your repository, either.

Your best bet is to fix your repository by filtering out the entire `node_modules` directory.  The [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) describes how to do this.  You can then add the following to `.gitignore` in a new commit to prevent yourself from accidentally re-adding it:

```
node_modules
```

If you are absolutely certain that you have a good and compelling reason to store this data in your repository, then you can install Git LFS, run `git lfs install`, then run `git lfs migrate import --everything --include='*.Framework'`.

Either of these scenarios will result in you rewriting history; that's unavoidable here.

Comment: can you help me with it yourself as I am a beginner?please

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with how to do the filtering, so the documentation really is your best bet.  `git filter-branch` is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0):

git lfs migrate import --include="*.framework"